# Learning PHP - is there a php alternative to http://tryruby.org/?

Tags: php, ruby

I've got a friend trying to learn php (they've never used a programming/scripting language before). They have a minimal understanding of html. I've used tryruby.org a little bit once, and I'm hoping there's something similar for php. I learned using books, but I don't want them to have to go through setting up a server on their localhost right now.

Ideas?

Comment: PHP can be run from the command line. You dont need a webserver unless you want to display HTML pages.

Comment: I've no knowledge of a decent online PHP demo, but for windows packages like XAMPP are trivially easy to set up.

Comment: Yeah, try the PHP cli. You just run `php -a`  or install phpsh - http://www.phpsh.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They aren't tutorials like TryRuby, but you can use [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/SekLl) or [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/O2gsOfd7) to run snippets of PHP and lots of other languages.

Answer (score 2):

Your friend should definitely learn HTML *first*.

I got started in HTML, PHP, JavaScript, and jQuery from [W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com). Your friend should check it out.

Comment: Why should he learn HTML first? You dont need a single piece of HTML if you want to program PHP.